# How to get background task status from parent window in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have the following powershell scripts to start two background task. I could able to fetch the status of background task if I use wait parameter.

```
$TestResult1=start .\TestFile1.bat -NoNewWindow -PassThru -ErrorAction Stop  
$TestResult2=start .\TestFile2.bat -NoNewWindow -PassThru -Wait -ErrorAction Stop

if($TestResult1.ExitCode -gt 0){
    throw 'Exceptions in TestFile1.bat'
}

if($TestResult2.ExitCode -gt 0){
    throw 'Exceptions in TestFile2.bat'
}
```

Is there any way to fetch the status of background task without using wait parameter? In above example, I can able to fetch the status only from TestFile2.bat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't use `-Wait`, you can **use [`Wait-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/wait-process) with your `$TestResult1` and `$TestResult2` variables**, which, thanks to `-PassThru`, contain [`System.Diagnostics.Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.Process) instances representing the processes launched:

```
# Waits synchronously for both processes to terminate.
$TestResult1, $TestResult2 | Wait-Process 

# Now you can inspect the exit codes.
# NOTE: The .ExitCode property is only available after a process
#       has *terminated*. Before that, it effectively returns `$null`
#       (the underlying .NET exception that occurs is swallowed by PowerShell).
$TestResult1.ExitCode, $TestResult2.ExitCode
```

**If you want to perform other operations while waiting for the processes to terminate**, you can use the `.HasExited` property in a loop to periodically *test* if the process have terminated:

```
$leftToMonitor = $TestResult1, $TestResult2
do {  

  # Perform foreground operations...
  Write-Host . -NoNewLine; Start-Sleep 1

  # Check for processes that have already terminated.
  $exited, $leftToMonitor = $psToMonitor.Where({ $_.HasExited }, 'Split')
  foreach ($ps in $exited) {
    # Output the command line and the exit code as properties of a custom object.
    [pscustomobject] @{
      CommandLine = $ps.CommandLine
      ExitCode = $ps.ExitCode 
    ]
  }
} while ($leftToMonitor)
```

Note that `Wait-Process` also has a `-Timeout` parameter, and you can use `-TimeOut 0` to momentarily test if processes have exited, but note that for (each) process that hasn't exited, a *non-terminating error* is reported, which makes checking the `.HasExited` property more convenient (and doing so is also faster).

---

That said, **for *invisible background tasks* I recommend using
[*PowerShell jobs*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Jobs), either via [`Start-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job), or, preferably, via the faster and lighter-weight [`Start-ThreadJob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/threadjob/start-threadjob)** (comes with PowerShell (Core) 7+, installable with `Install-Module ThreadJob` in Windows PowerShell) for background tasks rather than [`Start-Process -NoNewWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process), because they:

- avoid the problem of potential output from the `Start-Process -NoNewWindow`-launched process printing output that *cannot be captured* to the console, which without `-Wait` will arrive with unpredictably timing.
- instead allow you to collect output in a controlled manner on demand via the [`Receive-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/receive-job) cmdlet.
- Waiting for jobs to finish, optionally with a timeout, is done via the [`Wait-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/wait-job) cmdlet.

**Note**:

- `Start-Job` creates a hidden PowerShell *child* process in which to run given commands, which is what makes it slow, whereas `Start-ThreadJob` uses a *thread* in the current process.
- As of PowerShell 7.1, background jobs do *not* automatically capture the exit code of an / the most recent external program executed by them, unlike in *foreground* execution, where the automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable reflects this information. Therefore, unfortunately, `$LASTEXITCODE` must be reported as part of each job's *output*, which is cumbersome - see below.

  - [GitHub proposal #5422](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5422) suggests adding a `.LastExitProperty` to job objects to address this limitation.

---

**Examples:**

Note:

- Instead of calling a *batch file*, the examples below call a `cmd.exe` command *directly*, with `/c`, but the principle is the same.
- As stated, the exit code of the `cmd.exe` call must be reported *as part of the job's output*, hence the extra `; $LASTEXITCODE` statement after  the call.

**Simplistic example**: Wait synchronously for all jobs to terminate, and report the output, which comprises all stdout and stderr output from `cmd.exe` followed by the process exit code reported via `$LASTEXITCODE`:

```
# Start two thread jobs that call cmd.exe, with different outputs
# and different exit code.
# Note: If you don't have Start-ThreadJob, you can use Start-Job
$jobs = 
  (Start-ThreadJob { cmd /c 'echo ONE'; $LASTEXITCODE }),
  (Start-ThreadJob { cmd /c 'echo TWO & exit /b 1'; $LASTEXITCODE })

$jobs | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```

The above yields (note that the output order isn't guaranteed):

```
ONE
0
TWO
1
```

**Example with continued foreground operation while waiting**:

```
# Start two thread jobs that call cmd.exe, with different outputs
# and different exit code.
# Note: If you don't have Start-ThreadJob, you can use Start-Job
$jobs = 
  (Start-ThreadJob { cmd /c echo ONE; $LASTEXITCODE }),
  (Start-ThreadJob { cmd /c 'echo TWO & exit /b 1'; $LASTEXITCODE })

do {
  
  # Perform foreground operations...
  Write-Host . -NoNewLine; Start-Sleep 1

  # Note: You can also capture *ongoing* job output via repeated Receive-Job calls.
  
  # Find all all jobs that have finished.
  $finished, $jobs = $jobs.Where({ $_.State -in 'Completed', 'Failed', 'Stopped' }, 'Split') 

  # Process all finished jobs.
  foreach ($job in $finished) {

    # Get the job's output and separate it into the actual output
    # and the exit code, which is the *last* object.
    $output = $job | Receive-Job
    $i = 0
    $lastExitCode, $actualOutput = $output.Where({ ++$i -eq $output.Count }, 'Split')

    # Output a custom object that reflects the original command, the output, and the exit code.
    [pscustomobject] @{
      Command = $job.Command
      Output = $($actualOutput) # unwrap a single-object output collection
      ExitCode = $lastExitCode
    }

    # Remove the job 
    Remove-Job $job

  }
} while ($jobs)
```

Note:

The above uses the fairly cumbersome `$_.State -in 'Completed', 'Failed', 'Stopped'` to *momentarily* test for finished jobs, *without waiting*.
Ideally, `Wait-Job -Timeout 0` could more simply be used, but as of PowerShell 7.1 that doesn't work as expected (the minimum wait period is therefore `-Timeout 1`, i.e. 1 second) - see [GitHub issue #14675](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14675).